# Can client credentials grant access token be mapped to a user?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to use the Client Credentials Grant in oauth2 for securing an API.

However, I want the access token to map to an individual user (chosen by me, at the out-of-band trust/setup phase where I share a key/secret).

Is this an issue? I understand that the access token using client credentials grant is not supposed to be in the context of a user... Is it bad practice to bind it that way?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an issue per se, at least security-wise, although you may call it bad practice. If you make sure that you assign the client credentials in such a way that it is guaranteed to be bound to exactly one user for which that client is authorized, there's no problem. Note though that the out-of-band process to achieve that is exactly what the Authorization Code grant gives you in-band.

You'll also have to make sure that the client credentials are revoked when required permissions for the user change or the user account is deleted, much like a regular Authorization Server would do for its refresh tokens.

Comment: Hi Hans - thanks for this - the reason I chose to do this out-of-band is because we're individually controlling those who we want to use the API. Also, the API calls that occur will be 'system-to-system' cron jobs rather than requiring any user interaction. Am I wrong to use this grant for this approach? The only reason I'm tying the client_credentials to a specific user is that each client has 1 admin that controls the data for their institution...

Comment: if you can authenticate the admin to the Authorization Server, then you can issue a refresh token with the Code grant that would give you what you want; refresh tokens can be used to obtain new access tokens like client credentials, but the difference is that you've established the relationship between token and admin in-band

Comment: What about in the use case of using client_credentials for automated tests to simulate a user? Authorization Code is not an option, and password is deprecated, so client_credentials seems like a good fit there to me, maybe with shortened token lifetime and user whitelisting