# API-Token feature in IAM system

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

In an Identity and Access Management System - how is an "API-Token" feature typically implemented? That users can generate API-Token in their self-service-center, maybe restrict this tokens and then use them instead of their account credentials for M2M-Communication. (I am NOT speaking about the OAuth2 access_token or refresh_token)

It looks like the OAuth 2 Client Credentials Flow is perfect for that, but [Can client credentials grant access token be mapped to a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538415/can-client-credentials-grant-access-token-be-mapped-to-a-user) suggests that it can be called bad practice. I haven't found a IAM-Product that offers Client Credentials that are tied to users.

Thanks in advance for any input on how that is typically implemented or products that feature something like that, ... !

Answer (score 0):

Having found no ready solution I posted my unfinished thoughts about self-implementing it using Keycloak [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/create-api-token-that-are-impersonating-a-user/8665/2) (you are not forced to use Keycloak though, but OpenSource is nice since you need to modify/extend the IAM System).

> **Idea:**
> In some sense, the OAuth 2 client-credentials Flow seems perfect. The User-App exchanges the client_credentials with short-lived access_token, uses these to access the API. Before expiry, the App can request new access_token the same way.
>
> Service Accounts could be generated for each API-Token and they could be somehow linked to the user. Or client_credentials could be added to the User Credential Store of an existing user. Some custom Keycloak-Extension will be necessary either way.
>
> **Problem:**
> The Token generated for the App-Login are liked to itself as azp and not to e.g. our forum, ... . This will make the normal authorization-flow unusable. Additionally the /userinfo-Endpoint seems to be nearly unpopulated for service accounts.
>
> **Solution idea:**
> You will have to assign the azp to the service some way -
>
> - fetch it from a Request-Parameter during client_id validation
> - store it with the token
>
> According to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099677/keycloak-uma-grant-type-tickets-for-service-accounts-do-not-seem-to-work-with-po) (and own testing with Version 15.0.2), you can assign a service-account a hardcoded protocol-mapper with azp as key and the App-ID you want to use the token with as value. I wonder however if this was intended as a feature and how future-proof this is. This will also populate the /userinfo Endpoint.